# Django redirect cannot resolve URL

Tags: python, django

I have a pretty simple Django app with a form. After the form has been validated, it's supposed to redirect to the start page of the app. I get the following error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'overview' not found.
'overview' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

The relevant path in urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('overview', views.overview, name='overview'),
...]
```

The view is in the same views.py as the redirecting view:

```
def overview(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'feedback/overview.html', context)
```

The view with the redirect call looks like this:

```
def make_submission(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FeedbackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.approved = False
            post.save()
            return redirect('overview')
    else:
        form = FeedbackForm()
    return render(request, 'feedback/make_submission.html', {'form': form})
```

The form data are saved in the db, but the redirect fails. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Here's the main urls.py. Does it have anything to do with the fact that i'm usinf url() here instead of path()? I'm currently in the process of migrating the whole shebang to Django 2.1.

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^main/', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^feedback/', include('feedback.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Did you defined any namespace in root urls.py? I am assuming that your app name is `feedback`, can you try: `redirect('feedback:overview')`

Comment: post the code of your main urls

Comment: Hey, redirect('feedback:overview') worked! See OP for more. You guys rock!

Answer (score 1):

Your exception comes from [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/resolvers.py#L617):

```
    if patterns:
        if args:
            arg_msg = "arguments '%s'" % (args,)
        elif kwargs:
            arg_msg = "keyword arguments '%s'" % (kwargs,)
        else:
            arg_msg = "no arguments"
        msg = (
            "Reverse for '%s' with %s not found. %d pattern(s) tried: %s" %
            (lookup_view_s, arg_msg, len(patterns), patterns)
        )
    else:
        msg = (
            "Reverse for '%(view)s' not found. '%(view)s' is not "
            "a valid view function or pattern name." % {'view': lookup_view_s}
        )
```

This means that Django couldn't even find your url to try to reverse to it. Thus you probably included it incorrectly in core app's `urls.py` for the way you try to reference it. Probably fxgx's comment is correct.